# How can I use Server.MapPath() from global.asax?

Tags: c#, asp.net, global-asax, server.mappath, application-start

I need to use `Server.MapPath()` to combine some files path that I store in the `web.config`.

However, since `Server.MapPath()` relies on the current HttpContext (I think), I am unable to do this.  When trying to use the method, even though its "available", I get the following exception:

> Server operation is not available in this context.

Is there another method that can map a web root relative directory such as `~/App_Data/` to the full physical path such as `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\project\App_data\` ?

Answer (score 312, accepted):

You could try [System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting.hostingenvironment.mappath.aspx).

No HttpContext required.

Comment: Any caveats to this technique?

Comment: Nope. If you fire up Reflector, you'll notice that Server.MapPath and Request.MapPath ultimately call VirtualPath.MapPath which ultimately calls HostingEnvironment.MapPath. They all end up in the same place. HostingEnvironment.MapPath cuts out the middle man.

Comment: +1 this fixed an open source project that was working for me then just stopped initializing due to HttpContext.Current.Server blowing up for it not having a context for some reason. Switching to this put it back to smooth sailing.

Answer (score 5):

Use `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` because `Context` might return null !!

Answer (score 1):

When in Global.asax, use the ***context*** object:

context.Server.mappath()

Context lets you access also the session collection, the request object, the response object. Very useful when you want to log errors, for example

Comment: There is no guaranteed `Context` in Global.asax.

Answer (score -5):

You could try HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/") - That's how I have referenced it before in classes.

Comment: You can reference it like that in classes that actually HAVE an HttpContext, but I don't think global.asax has one, hence the error message I received.