# RazorEngine - How do I use my own HTML helper?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razorengine

I have the following in a RazorEngine template:

```
@using WAND.Helpers
@model Tour.Entities.Accommodation

<p>
    You can view your WAND accommodation home page by @Html.HomepageActionLink("Accommodation","clicking here",@Model.AccommodationId)
</p>
```

The HomePageActionLink is a helper I wrote that looks, in part, like this:

```
    public static MvcHtmlString HomepageActionLink(this HtmlHelper helper, string serviceProviderType, string linkText, int idValue )
    {
        ...

        return new MvcHtmlString(link);
    }
```

The problem is that when I run this, I get an error saying:

```
More details about the error: - error: (64, 60) The name 'Html' does not exist in the current context
```

Is there a way I can get this to work?

Comment: Which line gives you that error?

Comment: Have you added a `using` statement in the view to the assembly your helper is in (or added the assembly in the `web.config` file)?

Comment: @DavidG - The line where I'm calling Html.HomepageActionLink

Comment: Have you tried the fully qualifiied type name => System.Web.Mvc.Html.HomepageActionLink ?

Comment: @CodeNotFound - How exactly would I code that so that line is not interpreted as straight HTML text?

Comment: This code looks fine to me. I think you missed to post some other information in the question which might help us to help you

Comment: Are you using MVC6? If so,  just change HtmlHelper to IHtmlHelper.

Comment: Do the normal HTMLHelpers work, such as `@Html.ActionLink(...)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override BaseTemplateType with class which has Html implementation.
Like

```
var config = new TemplateServiceConfiguration();
        // MvcHtmlStringFactory code from 
        // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19431365/razorengine-html-helpers-work-but-escape-the-html
        config.EncodedStringFactory = new MvcHtmlStringFactory();

        // HtmlTemplateBase code from
        // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8561164/razorengine-issues-with-html
        config.BaseTemplateType = typeof(HtmlTemplateBase<>);
        var service = RazorEngineService.Create(config);

        var Colmodel ="@Html.BeginForm(\"UploadDocument\", \"Detail\", new{a=1,b=2})";

        string res = service.RunCompile(Colmodel, Colmodel,
            model.GetType(), model);
```