# RazorEngine - @Html.LabelFor OK, @Html.EditorFor "not implemented exception" on Execute()

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razorengine

I am evaluating RazorEngine at the moment to see if it can be used in our project - we need to reorder the fields in a view dynamically, so I'm trying to send a string to RazorEngine to get the full HTML and show that to the user.

I have used RazorEngine with @Html.LabelFor() and it works fine. I used mao47's code on this SO post:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/19434112/2878135
which is based on Abu Haider's code:
http://www.haiders.net/post/HtmlTemplateBase.aspx

But this does not work for @Html.EditorFor() . I get a System.NotImplementedException thrown -  method or operation is not implemented.
This is from a new MVC4 project. No code changes have been made other than to implement the code from mao47.

I have the RazorEngine source code and the error arises on the call to Execute() in

```
ITemplate.Run(ExecuteContext context)
```

The stack trace reads as thus:

```
[NotImplementedException: The method or operation is not implemented.]
System.Web.HttpContextBase.get_Items() +29
System.Web.Mvc.Html.TemplateHelpers.GetActionCache(HtmlHelper html) +93
System.Web.Mvc.Html.TemplateHelpers.ExecuteTemplate(HtmlHelper html, ViewDataDictionary viewData, String templateName, DataBoundControlMode mode, GetViewNamesDelegate getViewNames, GetDefaultActionsDelegate getDefaultActions) +132
System.Web.Mvc.Html.TemplateHelpers.TemplateHelper(HtmlHelper html, ModelMetadata metadata, String htmlFieldName, String templateName, DataBoundControlMode mode, Object additionalViewData, ExecuteTemplateDelegate executeTemplate) +1646
System.Web.Mvc.Html.TemplateHelpers.TemplateHelper(HtmlHelper html, ModelMetadata metadata, String htmlFieldName, String templateName, DataBoundControlMode mode, Object additionalViewData) +94
System.Web.Mvc.Html.TemplateHelpers.TemplateFor(HtmlHelper`1 html, Expression`1 expression, String templateName, String htmlFieldName, DataBoundControlMode mode, Object additionalViewData, TemplateHelperDelegate templateHelper) +228
System.Web.Mvc.Html.TemplateHelpers.TemplateFor(HtmlHelper`1 html, Expression`1 expression, String templateName, String htmlFieldName, DataBoundControlMode mode, Object additionalViewData) +140
System.Web.Mvc.Html.EditorExtensions.EditorFor(HtmlHelper`1 html, Expression`1 expression) +93
CompiledRazorTemplates.Dynamic.aadebbaabbddd.Execute() +329
RazorEngine.Templating.TemplateBase.RazorEngine.Templating.ITemplate.Run(ExecuteContext context) in c:\_git\RazorEngine\src\Core\RazorEngine.Core\Templating\TemplateBase.cs:126
RazorEngine.Templating.TemplateService.Run(ITemplate template, DynamicViewBag viewBag) in c:\_git\RazorEngine\src\Core\RazorEngine.Core\Templating\TemplateService.cs:608
RazorEngine.Templating.TemplateService.Parse(String razorTemplate, Object model, DynamicViewBag viewBag, String cacheName) in c:\_git\RazorEngine\src\Core\RazorEngine.Core\Templating\TemplateService.cs:439
RazorEngine.Razor.Parse(String razorTemplate, T model) in c:\_git\RazorEngine\src\Core\RazorEngine.Core\Razor.cs:263
TestRazorEngine.Controllers.AccountController.Test() in c:\~\TestRazorEngine\Controllers\AccountController.cs:47
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this is that there was no HttpContext or WebPageContext in the my Html Template.
I've answered this over in [Calling RazorEngine.Parse() in Controller Action fails with bad HttpContextBase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20545343/calling-razorengine-parse-in-controller-action-fails-with-bad-httpcontextbase) with code, but essentially you must call a controller action as usual (return PartialView(model)). In the .cshtml call RenderAction() specifying another controller action which gets the model and calls RazorEngine with the template (in my case just a string).

This way the context is completely fine for MVC to use when RazorEngine calls into it from Execute().

Answer (score 0):

The EditorFor need a folder in your subview folder called EditorTemplates, so you have a directory tree like this /Views/yourViews/EditorTemplates i give you an example

in the main view

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Destinatario)
```

in the subfolder the file Destinatario.cshtml

```
@model Domain.Models.Entities.Destinatario

<div class="item-destinatario">
<span data-action="view-destinatario">@Model.Nome</span>    

@Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.Id)
@Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.Tabella)
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Nome)
</div>
```

Edit: i forgot the model

```
public class Destinatario
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Tabella { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Cellulare { get; set; }
    public string Fax { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, this question relates to RazorEngine which sits on top of Razor. Google also gets confused when I use it to look for "RazorEngine".

Comment: oh so sorry for the useless answer :(

Comment: No worries - I appreciate that you were trying to help.