# How to parse a Razor template with partials from a custom folder?

Tags: razor, razorengine

I have two cshtml-files in the same subfolder of Views. One of the templates is meant to include the other template. I tried to accomplish that as follows:

Main template:

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    @Html.Partial("~/Views/Pdfs/Header");
  </body>
</html>
```

The error I get is

> Unable to compile template. The name 'Html' does not exist in current context.

What am I supposed to do additionally?

Comment: possible duplicate of [RazorEngine issues with @Html](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8561164/razorengine-issues-with-html)

Answer (score 3):

As commented by Erik there is no Html in RazorEngine (see the linked answer), however you can use `@Include("mytemplate")` instead.

If you want to be compatible with the `@Html.Partial()` syntax for some reason you can extend the RazorEngine syntax like [this](https://matthid.github.io/RazorEngine/TemplateBasics.html#Extending-the-template-Syntax).

Basically what you want to do is provide your own class inheriting from `TemplateBase<T>` (or `ITemplate` to be exact) and then set it either via configuration or the `@Inherit MyBaseClass<MyModel>` syntax. In this case you could just call the `Include` method from your `Partial` method within the Html helper class.

Answer (score 1):

Been annoyed by this for a long time. Wrote all the infrastructure classes to just get this working like you'd expect in MVC, without all the MVC burden:

```
var razor = RazorHelper.O;
var html = razor.RenderFromMvc(@"Views\RazorEngine\TestEmail.cshtml", vm);
```

https://github.com/b9chris/RazorEngineComplete

Comment: what's `O`? `vm` is view model?

Comment: Yes, vm is a ViewModel. O is a Singleton. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern