# adding namespaces when using RazorEngine

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razorengine

I am currently using the RazorEngine library to create html Email templates. Code:

```
var result = Engine.Razor.RunCompile(File.ReadAllText(templateFilePath), key, typeof(T), data);
```

Within the template itself I want to get access to some of the helper methods provided by MVC, namely `@Html.Format(string string);`

However Whenever I add said line of code in the template is:

> Errors while compiling a Template.
>   Please try the following to solve the situation:   * If the problem is
>   about missing/invalid references or multiple defines either try to
>   load 
>       the missing references manually (in the compiling appdomain!) or
>       Specify your references manually by providing your own IReferenceResolver implementation.
>       See https://antaris.github.io/RazorEngine/ReferenceResolver.html for details.
>       Currently all references have to be available as files!   * If you get 'class' does not contain a definition for 'member': 
>           try another modelType (for example 'null' to make the model dynamic).
>           NOTE: You CANNOT use typeof(dynamic) to make the model dynamic!
>       Or try to use static instead of anonymous/dynamic types. More details about the error:
>    - error: (180, 97) The name 'Html' does not exist in the current context

Which does explain that I need to reference the right namespace. Question is, what do I reference and where?

Comment: Have you found solution for this?

Comment: Have you found solution for this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RazorEngine issues with @Html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8561164/razorengine-issues-with-html)

Answer (score -2):

Are you looking for HtmlHelper in `System.Web.Mvc` ?

Ref: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.htmlhelper_methods(v=vs.118).aspx